# Is it good practice to delete your own answers to closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-answers

I just deleted my own +3 answer to a closed (duplicate) question because the question was an *exact* duplicate and therefore I didn't see the point in leaving it.

Is this good practice?

Comment: even if it were good practice I'd be surprised to see many people that are willing to give up the 30 points they'd lose at the next rep recalc

Comment: @Conrad But you get the Disciplined badge :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your answer would still make sense on the original question (and it's not just repeating another answer that's already there), it would probably be better to flag the question for merging.

There's also no harm in just leaving the answer alone.  If someone finds the duplicate first in a Google search, they might find it useful to have an answer on the same page, rather than having to click through to the original.

Answer (score 13):

If the answer was good (and it was not provided by the original question), it is not good.

You could flag for moderator attention and have the answer moved to the original question, or you could have left it.

Remember that good answers, are more valuable than bad questions.